# Android app connecting IMDB

Tags: java, android, html, xml

today I used Android Studio 1.4 for the first time. I decided to make a app that helps you find a movie to watch. Very basic. Main page with a buttom that sends you to a random movie with tittle, poster, imdb link and a buttom that sends you to a new random movie.

I got two problems.

1. The Mainpage buttom that sends the user to a random activity is not working. How can i code it so it will send the user to a random activity and preferred not the same one. Can you make it choose from 1 of 100 activities?
2. I only get a error when I try to bind the Imdb link to a button.

Comment: You should make 1 activity for all the movies and make the content generic instead of making unique activities for each movie.

Comment: This is entirely too broad a question.  And what you are trying to build is hardly "very basic".

Answer (score 0):

Well your asking a question which requires to do some looking around. You are asking some basic question, which you should be able to do.

Here is a little code that you can use

```
Button yourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.your_buttons_id);

yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){                        
        startActivity(new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, YourNewActivity.class));
    }
});
```

I personally feel like you need to check some tuts online. This is the basic, if you struggle on this, then you would struggle a lot more else where.

Anyway, if you see **findViewById(R.id.your_buttons_id);** it lets the app know which button that was clicked.